# Check JSON for img tag and change src in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, image

We have a custom made CRM which saves the IMG's in our database as `/upload/image/image.jpg` but we also have images that have the full url. I need a way to find out if an image starts with /upload and add our web address to the front of that image src so that the image shows up correctly and does not get a square with no image,

We are using JSON and javascript here is the code we have so far

```
function loadnewsstory(e)
{

    if(newsview !== true)
    {
        document.getElementById("newsarticals").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("activecontent").style.display = "none";
        newsview = true;
    }


    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://media.queerdio.com/mobileDevice/?uri=loadstory/"+e ,false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    var newsreponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var news = newsreponse[0];

    document.getElementById("newsarticals").innerHTML = '<h1 class="newsheader">' + news.post_title + '</h1> <div class="newsbody">'+news.post_content+'</div>';
    window.scrollTo(0,0);

}
```

The part we need to look at is `news.post_content`.

EDIT:
Added what the JSON looks like

```
"post_content":"<p>DR SHARON Giese is a household name in America, starring on hit medical shows Dr Oz and The Doctors and making regular appearances on CBS News, CNN and NBC.<\/p>\n<p>Dr Giese is ranked among the best in her field but, as one family discovered \"with tragic consequences\" even the best make mistakes.<\/p>\n<center><img src=\"..\/..\/..\/upload\/Health\/Dr Sharon Giese - Dr OZ - YouTube.jpg\" alt=\"Dr Oz Show - DR SHARON\" width=\"650\" height=\"488\" \/><\/center>\n<div style=\"padding: 0; margin: -6px 0 4px 10px; text-align: left;\">A screen grab from a recent appearance on the Dr Oz show. Picture: YouTube Source: YouTube<\/div>\n<p>In June 2009, 32-year-old mother-of-two Adriana Porras underwent liposuction, a fat reduction procedure performed by Dr Giese. Ms Porras died two days later of a pulmonary embolism.<\/p>\n<p>Her husband Pablos Balzola then sued Dr Giese for negligence, claiming she did not return their frantic calls when Ms Porras showed signs of severe post-surgery complications, complaining of chest pains and shortness of breath.<\/p>\n<p>In court, pathologists testified that had she received treatment for those symptoms, her chance of survival would have been much higher.<\/p>\n<p>It was later found out that Dr Giese had not performed the procedure in a hospital but in her own home office.<\/p>\n<p>This week she finally reached a settlement with Mr Balzola, agreeing to pay US$2.3 million (AUD$2.5 million)<\/p>\n<p>The money will reportedly be split between the widower, his six-year-old daughter Maia and nine-year-old son Nicholas. Mr Balzola"
```

I have used this code for our feature_images

```
 if(news.featured_image.substring(0, 7) !== "http://")
        {
        news.featured_image = "http://www.radiobreakout.com.au/"+news.featured_image;
        }
```

But how do I get it to look at img srcs in the post_content.

Comment: What does `news.post_content` look like? Is it an image tag?

Comment: If you are looking for a search and replace of strings beginning with '/upload', then `var str = '/upload/string';
var res = str.replace(/^\/upload/, "myurlprefix"+"$&");` should do it.

Comment: but how would that work when all of our images are in upload and we can not be sure that all links will be in that formate we need to check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider this:

```
var articles = document.getElementById('newsarticals');
var activeContent = document.getElementById('activecontent');
var httpUrl = /^http:/;
function loadnewsstory(e) {
    if (newsview !== true) {
        articles.style.display = 'block';
        activeContent.style.display = 'none';
        newsview = true;
    }

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST','http://media.queerdio.com/mobileDevice/?uri=loadstory/' + e , false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    // empty the articles element first
    while (articles.children.length) articles.removeChild(articles.firstChild);
    // create a document fragment out of the response
    var newsArray = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var newsEl = newsArray.reduce(function htmlCreator(frag, news) {
        // create the elements properly first
        var header = document.createElement('h1');
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        header.className = 'newsheader';
        header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(news.post_title));
        // innerHTML shouldn't really be used, but we'll let it slide this time
        // next time don't store html in json
        div.innerHTML = news.post_content;
        div.className = 'newsbody';
        // loop through all of the newly added images to change the sources
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(div.querySelectorAll('img'), function sourceMangler(el) {
            if (!httpUrl.test(el.src)) el.src = 'http://www.radiobreakout.com.au/' + el.src.split('/').filter(function removeSome(part) { return (part && part !== '..'); }).join('/');
        });
        frag.appendChild(header);
        frag.appendChild(div);
        return frag;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    // append the fragment to the empty element
    articles.appendChild(newsEl);
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Comment: It works but not for inside an android app - so yes it is correct but don't use this code on android html web apps which use Cordova

Comment: Can you be more specific on which part doesn't work, I'd like to know if I can change the example to solve the problem.